# PySide: Create window at a position based on the position of existing UI elements

Tags: popup, position, pyside, maya

I'm creating a tool in Maya that has some popups.  I'd like the popups to appear at a set location based on the UI element that you've clicked.

When I run the script the tool appears at my cursor location (this works fine).  Then, when you left click the button another window pops up (this does not work fine).

The problem is that the popup window is appearing on the top left of my screen and not at the QPushButton's location.  I figured that if I replaced QtGui.QCursor.pos() with self.button_popup.pos() in the move_ui method of my Popup_Window class it would work... but it didn't.

Any thoughts? This is what I have so far with key areas commented on the right:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from shiboken import wrapInstance 

def get_parent():
    ptr = mui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    return wrapInstance( long( ptr ), QtGui.QWidget )

############################################
class RightClickMenuButton(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = get_parent() ):
        super(RightClickMenuButton, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ActionsContextMenu)

        # Commands
        self.move_UI()
        self.create_gui()
        self.create_layout()
        self.create_connections()

    #-------------------------------------------
    def create_gui(self):
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton()

    #-------------------------------------------
    def create_layout(self):
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    #-------------------------------------------
    def move_UI( self ):
        ''' Moves the UI to the cursor's position '''
        pos = QtGui.QCursor.pos()
        self.move(pos.x()+20, pos.y()+15)

    #-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-
    def create_connections(self):
        # Left click
        self.button.clicked.connect( self.on_left_click )

        # Right click delete
        delete = QtGui.QAction(self)
        delete.setText("remove")
        delete.triggered.connect(self.remove_button)
        self.addAction(delete)

    #-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-
    def remove_button(self):
        self.deleteLater()

    def on_left_click(self):
        self.popup = Popup_Window(self, self.button )      # Passing button in so I can get it's position
        self.popup.show()

############################################
class Popup_Window( QtGui.QDialog ):
    def __init__( self, mainUIWindow, button ):
        super( Popup_Window, self ).__init__()

        self.button_pos = button                           # Creating variable 
        self.mainUIWindow = mainUIWindow
        self.setAttribute( QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose )

        # Commands
        self.move_UI()
        self.create_gui()
        self.create_layout()

    #-------------------------------------------
    def move_UI( self ):
        ''' Moves the UI to the cursor's position '''
        pos = self.button_pos.pos()                        # Using the button's position to determine window position
        self.move(pos.x()+20, pos.y()+15)

    #-------------------------------------------
    def create_gui( self ):
        ''' Visible GUI stuff '''
        self.push_btn = QtGui.QPushButton( "Create" )

    #-------------------------------------------
    def create_layout( self ):
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel( "Hey" )
        self.button_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.button_layout.addWidget( self.push_btn )

############################################
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Things to fix PySide Maya bug
    try:
        test_ui.close()
        test_ui.deleteLater()
    except:
        pass

    test_ui = RightClickMenuButton()
    test_ui.show()

    try:
        test_ui.show()
    except:
        test_ui.close()
        test_ui.deleteLater()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `widget.pos()` gives you the relative position of the widget (relative to the window) that is pretty small, nearly (0,0), that is top left corner in window space.

If you want the global screen position of a widget you have to write:

```
rel_pos = widget.pos()
pos = widget.mapToGlobal(rel_pos)
```

So your *move_UI* function in *Popup_Window* class become:

```
def move_UI( self ):
        ''' Moves the UI to the widget position '''
        rel_pos = self.button_pos.pos()                        # Using the button's position to determine window position
        pos = self.button_pos.mapToGlobal(rel_pos)
        self.move(pos.x()+20, pos.y()+15)
```